# Why does Selenium / Jenkins report two different ChromeDriver versions?

Tags: selenium, jenkins

When I run Selenium jobs through Jenkins, I see 2 different ChromeDriver versions reported:

**Expected**

```
17:00:29.375 [TestNG-test=wsc tests-3] WARN  c.r.a.p.c.c.CreditApplicationPage - Unable to locate field: {} 
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//form[@name='creditAppDynaValidatorActionForm']//span[@class='message']"}
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615279 (12b89733300bd268cff3b78fc76cb8f3a7cc44e5),platform=Linux 3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'jenkins-slave-4368551bbabf', ip: '172.17.45.11', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_152'
```

The `Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615279` makes sense to me. This is the driver version we've installed.

**Alternate**

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//form[@name='creditAppDynaValidatorActionForm']//span[@class='message']"}
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=70.0.3538.67 (9ab0cfab84ded083718d3a4ff830726efd38869f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'jenkins-slave-4368551bbabf', ip: '172.17.45.11', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_152'
```

What does the `Driver info: chromedriver=70.0.3538.67` mean; why is it displayed here? Version 70.0 is so very far off from 2.45.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague pointed me to the answer:

[image: selenium-grid]

The driver version reported is the WebDriver version as run through the Selenium Grid.

Comment: The best questions are one you answer on your own... :). Please don't forget to come back and mark this as the answer so that the question isn't left unanswered.